# Implementing Firebase analytics in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics

I'm creating an app that is using Firebase for analytics and they state on my events dash board that you just need to copy "the following code" in order to log the event signup as seen below.

[image]

How do you implement this into a Flutter app? And what is "Bundle"? When I copy this into my code, it doesn't know what "Bundle" is. I can't seem to find documentation for flutter to implement this particular event. Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: Bundle is a concept in Android. Copying Android Java code in to a Flutter/Dart project is unlikely to lead to much success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle) is a concept in Android. Copying Android Java code in to a Flutter/Dart project is unlikely to lead to much success.

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics is the package for flutter and it suggest using:

```
FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();

MaterialApp(
  home: MyAppHome(),
  navigatorObservers: [
    FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Thank you. I have actually already implemented this part of the code, but didn't realise it was the same thing as that "Bundle" thing. I've managed to implement a "login" event, but that was easy since it's practically premade. Still struggling to make custom events.

Comment: Also, does this not only track which pages are being navigated to?